# Where to store tokens in REST based project?

Tags: rest, ehcache

I am building a REST based application and i am creating tokens after user gets successfully authenticated. Now I want to know where to store tokens , in DB or cache(Ehcache). Which method is best in what scenerio.

If the tokens are in DB then we have to fetch token from DB to authenticate but cache gives best performance but i am little bit confuse in what scenerio which method should be used.

My application would have thousands of visitors in a single time.

Answer (score 1):

A cache is about temporary storage trading higher memory usage for lower latency. If you have no way of reconstructing the token in case it is evicted from the cache, then having them *only* in the cache is not an option. In this case you should store them in DB and cache them if you can measure performance benefits.